# MS Access 2007 2 table query getting category names by numbers?

Tags: sql, ms-access

It's been a while since I worked with MS Access & I've done this many times before but cannot find a way to describe this within a google search now so cannot find the answer;

I have 2 tables in a query; Table 1 has 3 columns containing numeric references to categories listed in table 2 by corresponding numbers & their names. I need to create a query that pulls the equivalent category name from table 2 that corresponds to the numbers in the columns of table 1 in all 3 columns.

Comment: You need a `JOIN` between your tables. Edit your answer to add a sample of your 2 tables, with the columns names and  just 2/3 lines of data. And only after you'll get the clear answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the setup is something like:

tblTable1:

```
Category1       Category2      Category3
1               4              7
```

tblTable2:

```
CategoryID          Category
1                   This
2                   That
3                   Something
4                   One
5                   Brown
6                   Mouse
7                   Shoe
```

As a basic framework, you would do something like this:

```
SELECT 
  tblTable2_1.Category as Category1, 
  tblTable2_2.Category as Category2, 
  tblTable2_3.Category as Category3
FROM tblTable1
LEFT JOIN tblTable2 AS tblTable2_1
  ON tblTable1.Category1 = tblTable2_1.CategoryID
LEFT JOIN tblTable2 AS tblTable2_2
  ON tblTable1.Category2 = tblTable2_2.CategoryID
LEFT JOIN tblTable2 AS tblTable2_3
  ON tblTable1.Category3 = tblTable2_3.CategoryID
```

This would give you the output:

```
Category1            Category2           Category3
This                 One                 Shoe
```